# HTML/CSS: Vertical label, located in the middle of the left edge of the container

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to achieve that without resorting to JavaScript? The problem seems to be that I need to specify `transform: translateX(...)` in terms of the container (since I want to move it 50% down), but applying "`transform: translateX(50%);`" would move it down by 50% of the `label`'s height.

Edit: adding the code snippet. This is pretty much what I want to achieve, except that I can't find a way to move the text down 50% relative to the container.

```css
.vertical {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-250px);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  float: left;  
}
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;background-color:gray">
  <label class="vertical"> Vertical text in the middle of the left edge
  </label>
<div>
```

Comment: what about some of your code?

Comment: Just added code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to transform the container than the element inside it.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/ot80y7ef/1/)

The example below centers the rotate div halfway down the page...and keeps it there on scrolling which I think is what you wanted. If you want the div to scroll with the page, use `position:absolute` instead.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  /* halfway down the page */
  transform-origin: top left;
  /* set the rotation point */
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 0%);
  /*rotate 90degs counter-clockwise AND move the element UP half it's width which is now it's height */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Vertical text in the middle of the left edge</p>
</div>
```